# GraphViz Dot. How to distribute elements around a boxed size?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a dot graphviz file that geneates the following output:

http://www.qlands.com/other_files/test.png

However the output is organized vertically. If I setup the size to be for example 8.27 inches; How can I distribute the elements around a box of 8.27 x 8.27 inches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graph is a directed graph layed out with dot from left to right, and the first rank contains many nodes which results in a very high image.

The main tool to break up graphs with this problem is [`unflatten`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf):

> **unflatten** is a preprocessor to dot that is used to improve the aspect
>   ratio of graphs having many leaves or disconnected nodes. The usual
>   layout for such a graph is generally very wide or tall. unflatten
>   inserts invisible edges or adjusts the minlen on edges to improve
>   layout compaction.

You may combine this with other tools and techniques to get the result you want:

- Use the `unflatten` utility - please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136488/63733) for a detailed example using unflatten.
- Use invisible edges to introduce new ranks (basically what unflatten does automatically, but with human inspiration... example also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136488/63733))
- If you need the output to be of this exact size, be sure to understand graphviz's various attributes which have an impact on it, such as `size`, `margin`, `ratio`... (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837414/63733) and [yet another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506152/63733) providing details)
- Finally, you could simply use a different layout (`neato` for example)